# Using PayPal REST API with Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rest, api, paypal

I have a number of old programs that I wrote in VB6 that use a Webbrowser control to log into PayPal and then fill in various PayPal fields in the browser based on actions taken by the user. PayPal has changed some things recently that make my old programs no longer work, so I'm upgrading.

I've started working in VB.NET (Visual Studio Express 2013) to try to replace my old forms based VB6 programs with VB.NET programs.

I'll be honest, I find the PayPal REST API instructions confusing and I see almost no examples in VB.

For starters, all I want to do is send customers invoices. I want to take the information for the invoices from my forms-based windows program (written in VB6) and submit it to the customer as a PayPal invoice with all the detail.

I have some code - not sure how good it is. Can someone get me started by telling me where it would go in a VB.NET app (Let's say you just started a brand new VB.NET forms-based app and wanted to put the support for the PayPal REST Invoicing API). I've written some programs in VB.net and C#.net, but I'm a bit green when it comes to things like Namespaces and Imports statements. Note - this code is translated from C# and there are some statements that seem to issue errors no matter where I put them (

I tried putting this code in AssemblyInfo.VB (note this is sample code so user ids and passwords are generic and not mine):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace InvoicingSampleApp
Public NotInheritable Class Configuration
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    ' Creates a configuration map containing signature credentials and other required configuration parameters
    Public Shared Function GetSignatureConfig() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim configMap As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

        ' Endpoints are varied depending on whether sandbox OR live is chosen for mode
        configMap.Add("mode", "sandbox")

        ' Account Credential
        configMap.Add("account1.apiUsername", "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com")
        configMap.Add("account1.apiPassword", "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F")
        configMap.Add("account1.apiSignature", "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy")
        configMap.Add("account1.applicationId", "APP-80W284485P519543T")

        ' Sandbox Email Address
        configMap.Add("sandbox.EmailAddress", "pp.devtools@gmail.com")

        Return configMap
    End Function

    ' Creates a configuration map containing certificate credentials and other required configuration parameters
    Public Shared Function GetCertificateConfig() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim configMap As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

        ' Endpoints are varied depending on whether sandbox OR live is chosen for mode
        configMap.Add("mode", "sandbox")

        ' Account Credential
        configMap.Add("account2.apiUsername", "certuser_biz_api1.paypal.com")
        configMap.Add("account2.apiPassword", "D6JNKKULHN3G5B8A")
        configMap.Add("account2.apiCertificate", "resource/sdk-cert.p12")
        configMap.Add("account2.privateKeyPassword", "password")
        configMap.Add("account2.applicationId", "APP-80W284485P519543T")


        ' Sandbox Email Address
        configMap.Add("sandbox.EmailAddress", "pp.devtools@gmail.com")

        Return configMap
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace




General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
associated with an assembly.
Review the values of the assembly attributes
<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("PaymentRequest")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("PaymentRequest")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2017")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")> 
<Assembly: ComVisible(False)>
The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
 <Assembly: Guid("bb86e41e-ee37-4fd5-8e6f-0fa12f364392")> 

' Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
 '
''      Major Version
''      Minor Version 
''      Build Number
''      Revision
''
'' You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision 
Numbers 
'' by using the '*' as shown below:
'' <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")> 

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

I have other code as well and more questions, but I'll stop there to limit the scope of this. Thanks for you help (and patience with my question)

Comment: [PayPal-NET-SDK looks pretty good](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK). I've never used it but there's plenty of stars and forks, and what looks like decent documentation.

Comment: If PayPal supports REST, you can look at a library like RestSharp to simplify the calls you need to make.  http://restsharp.org/